# How to differentiate between system calls and normal function calls

Tags: c++, unix, operating-system, rtos, qnx

I am working on project which is trying to migrate some legacy application running on QNX neutrino operating system to other open source RTOS based on linux. 
I have listed all the third party library and device drivers which must be ported and now analyzing design and source code which depends on some special QNX features like QNX IPC MsgSend, MsgReply, MsgSendPulse etc.

I want to know is there any tools which will help me to make a list of all QNX related system calls or functions which is getting used in code from normal user defined functions or functions provided by third party library and C++ library. Since code is written by other organisations we don't know much details about code except how to compiler and how to run it.

Thanks

Comment: The compiler/linker?  Remove the OS headers/libraries from the build and check out the error messages?

Comment: gcc is the compiler. Removing libraries how to do it ? since they get linked by default and also removing headers will be difficult since that will involve changing 100 of code. Is there any tool like eclipse CDT which will list all functions and then separate system calls .

Comment: "RTOS based on linux" is an oxymoron, Linux is not an RTOS.

Comment: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/lib_ref/summary.html

Comment: all system call http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/instr_en/instr/kercall_table.html

Comment: If you find links useful as answer let me know I will post as answers.@noname

Answer (score 0):

Please refer link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/simpl/

You don't have direct API calls in linux which are equivalent to MsgSend, MsgReply etc.. but you can achieve it through using existing pipes/POSIX MQs (or) You can install above tgz package (Which is available in https://sourceforge.net/projects/simpl/).